# Keras tensorboard callback not saving training/validation accuracies

Tags: keras, tensorboard

Currently, I am creating a Tensorboard callback object in Keras and adding it as a callback when calling my `fit` function.

However, when I run tensorboard, the only scalar values I see are `loss` and `val_loss`.

Is there a way to add additional scalar values such as `acc` and `val_acc` using the Keras callback for tensorboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorboard logs all defined metrics by default, did you add them to the model?
In my case I have even some custom metrics, which are logged in tensorboard, using keras callback.

```
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir='./graph', histogram_freq=0,  
          write_graph=True, write_images=True)    
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=[matthews_correlation, 'accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y,callbacks=[tensorboard], ...)
```

Comment: Is ```matthews_correlation``` a class extending the ```Callback``` class in Keras?

Comment: I want to write a custom metric that executes only on validation data, is there a way to specify this? I know you can do this with Keras Callbacks, but the data logged using the Keras Callback cannot be monitored using tensorboard. You can only visualize it after the training has finished